# Pattern behind the process id assignment

Tags: process

I know that the process ids are assigned by the system in order to uniquely identify them. Also, (by experience) I have noticed that they tend to increase in time. If for example I kill a process and restart it, it will typically take a large number id. A program which is initialized later it also would take large id than one which was invoked earlier.

I am curious about the actual pattern is being used to assign these number though. Is there a specific algorithm those numbers are assigned for example? Or are they assigned almost randomly without any specific reason behind the assignment?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/135007/how-are-pids-generated

Comment: ... also [Is the PID of a child process always greater than the PID of its parent on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466750/65304)